# Read Delta tables from ADLS to PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, databricks, azure-databricks, powerbi-desktop, azure-data-lake-gen2

**I am integrating ADLS with Databricks and want to load delta tables stored in ADLS to PowerBI.**

Each time I update the table a new parquet file is created in the ADLS directory location in addition to the original. It also adds a crc and json file which I assume are detailing the changes.
The table shows updates as expected when I reimport them in code via pyspark/databricks notebook but multiple parquet files seem to confuse PowerBI.

I can only get PowerBI to view the parquets individually or I can append them all together with an M script. This joined view does not show me the actual content of the latest table version (consider the case of removing a row).

**How can I display the complete latest table version?**

- I am using the ADLS 2 Data Connection option in PowerBI.
- Saving tables to ADLS using this command:
  *new_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(adls_path)*

Answer (score 1):

To properly read Delta files, you need a compute resource that can use the crc\json files to calculate the last version, like a Databricks cluster.
PowerBI does not know how to do it.

Your options are:

1. To convert your tables to regular Parquet files:

```
new_df.write.parquet.mode("overwrite").save(adls_path)
```

2. Connect from PowerBI to the databricks cluster : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/partners/bi/power-bi

Note - that means the cluster will be brought up to read the files and deliver the data to PowerBI on each refresh.

Comment: The files are stored on ADLS, if I connect through Databricks does that mean I need to mount the storage drive in the cluster workspace?

Comment: Yes, and create a database and tables based on these files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Power BI has native support for Delta tables from a ADLS, but can't be sure. We tend to use Delta Sharing, which is an easier way (and no running cluster) to access the data. And its also quite fast. But you need to be using Unity Catalog.